# Google analytics tracking flow from another domain

Tags: google, google-analytics

Is there a way to track the flow of Google Analytics from another domain using same UA code so that we can check the visitors flow?

So if someone enters the google.com/hello and the page refers to hello.com, can we track in same GA account so google.com/hello as a landing page and hello.com as the second page?

I tried but it didn't work. Is there other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not simple as you have to transfer cookie data between domains...

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look at the referral traffic to google.com/hello by the domain hello.com?

You do not need to use the same UA code.